# Vmware Nas slow transfer rates/IOPS

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi, network-attached-storage, synology

I have built a test environment with a Synology RS812+ and an old HP140 server which has a gigabit nic installed. I have dedicated one nic to the network to DHCP and the direct to NAS from the server over ISCI.

I am using esx 4.0 as the hypervisor, and  I am noticing slow speeds for example when creating a snapshot the transfer rates is around 20mb max.Also when looking at the NAS the reads/writes are not steady on the graph, it jumps for 10kb to 10mb and back down to 10kb?
Since then I have enabled Jumbo frames on the Nics and Vswitch and still the same issue.

Also I have run Vmware analyzer and tested different workloads which shows different results based the application ie exchange vs sql.on max iops test in analyzer it achieves up to 95mb which is pleasing.

Can anyone pass any thoughts on what is causing the issue please.

Hardware:
NAS:RS812+
 4 x 3 TB wd30efrx
Raid: SHR

Server:
HPDL140
1Gb NIC

Comment: Why are you using ESX 4? I just checked and it's definitely 2014

Comment: Its 4.1, its the latest one that worked with the hardware (DL140). production environment has the same issue but its on later hardware and using Esxi 5.5. I created this with old hardware as a test to try help solve the issue.